# Django-extension runscript No (valid) module for script

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-extensions

I'm trying to create a script that will populate my model `families` with informations extracted from a text file.
This is my first post in `StackOverflow`, please be gentle, sorry if the question is not well expressed or not correctly formatted.

Django V 1.9  and running on Python 3.5
Django-extensions installed

This is my model: *it's in an app called* `browse`

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel


class families(TimeStampedModel):
     rfam_acc = models.CharField(max_length=7)
     rfam_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=75)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     rfam_URL = models.URLField()
```

Here I have my script `familiespopulate.py`. Positioned in the `PROJECT_ROOT/scripts` directory.

```
import csv
from browse.models import families

file_path =       "/Users/work/Desktop/StructuRNA/website/scripts/RFAMfamily12.1.txt"

def run(file_path):
    listoflists = list(csv.reader(open(file_path, 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
    for row in listoflists:
        families.objects.create(
                rfam_acc=row[0],
                rfam_id=row[1],
                description=row[3],
                author=row[4],
                comment=row[9],
        )
```

When from Terminal i run:

```
python manage.py runscript familiespopulate
```

it returns:

```
No (valid) module for script 'familiespopulate' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3
```

The problem must be in importing the model `families`, I'm new to `django`, and I cannot find any solution here on `StackOverflow` or anywhere else online. 
This is why I ask for your help!

Do you know how the model should be imported? 
Or... Am I doing something else wrong.

Important piece of information is that the script runs if I modify it to PRINT out the parameters, instead of creating an object in families.

For your information and curiosity I will also post here an extract of the textfile that I'm using.

```
RF00001 5S_rRNA 1302    5S ribosomal RNA    Griffiths-Jones SR, Mifsud W, Gardner PP    Szymanski et al, 5S ribosomal database, PMID:11752286   38.00   38.00   37.90   5S ribosomal RNA (5S rRNA) is a component of the large ribosomal subunit in both prokaryotes and eukaryotes. In eukaryotes, it is synthesised by RNA polymerase III (the other eukaryotic rRNAs are cleaved from a 45S precursor synthesised by RNA polymerase I). In Xenopus oocytes, it has been shown that fingers 4-7 of the nine-zinc finger transcription factor TFIIIA can bind to the central region of 5S RNA. Thus, in addition to positively regulating 5S rRNA transcription, TFIIIA also stabilises 5S rRNA until it is required for transcription.    NULL    cmbuild -F CM SEED  cmcalibrate --mpi CM    cmsearch --cpu 4 --verbose --nohmmonly -T 24.99 -Z 549862.597050 CM SEQDB   712 183439  0   0   Gene; rRNA; Published; PMID:11283358    7946    0       0.59496 -5.32219    1600000 213632  305 119 1   -3.78120    0.71822 2013-10-03 20:41:44 2016-04-21 23:07:03
```

This is the first line and the result of the extraction from the listoflists is :

```
RF00002
5_8S_rRNA
5.8S ribosomal RNA
Griffiths-Jones SR, Mifsud W
5.8S ribosomal RNA (5.8S rRNA) is a component of the large subunit of    the eukaryotic ribosome. It is transcribed by RNA polymerase I as part of the 45S precursor that also contains 18S and 28S rRNA. Functionally, it is thought that 5.8S rRNA may be involved in ribosome translocation [2]. It is also known to form covalent linkage to the p53 tumour suppressor protein [3]. 5.8S rRNA is also found in archaea.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from adding **init**.py you are not supposed to pass any parameters in the run method.

```
def run():
     <your code goes here>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The init.py is present in the script directory. 
I tried to move the file_path definition inside def run(), but the execution still returns with this error: 
(.VirEnvStructuRna)  work@pboccaletto  ~/Desktop/StructuRNA/website   master ●  python manage.py runscript familiespopulate
Exception while running run() in 'scripts.familiespopulate'

Comment: Yes It is. I resolved the problem. And I'm going to post the solution now.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding empty file `__init__.py` (double underscore) into your /scipts folder and run with:

```
python manage.py runscript scipts.familiespopulate
```

Comment: I tried to execute your code but the result is the same. 

    python manage.py runscript scipts.familiespopulate
    No (valid) module for script 'scipts.familiespopulate' found
    Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the useful comments. 
I modified my code in this way:

```
import csv
from browse.models import families


def run():
   file_path =   "/Users/work/Desktop/StructuRNA/website/scripts/RFAMfamily12.1.txt"
   listoflists = list(csv.reader(open(file_path, 'r'),delimiter='\t'))
print(listoflists)
for row in listoflists:
    families.objects.create(
                rfam_acc=row[0],
                rfam_id=row[1],
                description=row[3],
                author=row[4],
                comment=row[9],
    )
```

This is all. Now it worked smoothly. 
I want to confirm to everyone that my file: familiespopulate.py was in the folder script with the file **init**.py

The problem seemed to be resolved when I put

```
file_path = "/Users/work/Desktop/StructuRNA/website/scripts/RFAMfamily12.1.txt"
```

Inside the run function, removing the parameter file_path from run(file_path).

Another modify to my code was the argument r inside open(file_path, 'r'), before it was open(file_path, 'rb') that should corrispond to read binary.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting exactly the same error, I tried all of the solution above but unfortunately did not worked for me. Then I realized my mistake, and I found it.

Inside the script file (which is inside the script/ folder) I used different name for the function, which should be named as 'run'. So, make sure you checked it as well, if you get this error.

[Here you can read more about "runscript"](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html)